# Can I decide over which version of http to send request?

Tags: javascript, http

Can I  decide on client side over which version of protocol to send the request http/1.x or http/2?

the backend switched to http/2 and now without any effort on front-end all the requests are sent via the  http/2. It happens that one specific request for image uploading takes really long - like 15-20 seconds. There was no such problem  before the switch. So until we find how to fix this I'd like  temporarily to go back to http/1 for this specific request. As far as I read http/2 is  backwards compatible - so  I  assume that somehow I can migrate to it gradually. We develop with  Angular 1.5 if it makes any difference.

Comment: please add more information on what you are trying to use this for

Comment: what is the "client-side" - node? browser?

Comment: @DanielA.White: That's a point. There I was assuming `XMLHttpRequest`, but...

Comment: @DanielA.White,  I meant browser

Comment: i dont think you can from a browser since the browser manages the entire request. what's the usecase?

Comment: Well, one idea is if the data that's getting uploaded is not too sensitive you could maybe use HTTP instead of HTTPS, as http/2 only works over HTTPS.  Even if security is an issue, you could still use HTTP, and use Javascript to encrypt the uploaded data, even using the HTTPS to get a key you could use to encrypt with.

Comment: @Keith, so can I  assume that https is the  bottleneck?

Comment: If you think `http/2` is causing you issues with uploading, to go back to http1.1 you can just use HTTP instead of HTTPS, this is because it was decided `http/2` was only allowed to run over HTTPS.

Comment: I understand now, I'll check whether this can be a possible temporarily solution